# Django, DRF Token authentication doesn't work, get Anonymous User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I'm quite new to Django. I want to make some authorization for mobile. I've read docs below:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme
Although I've read and done as it is written thoroughly it does not work. 
I have obtained a token for one of user but when I want to authenticate with this token there is no result and I get AnonymousUser.

```
{"token": "e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d"}

curl -X GET http://<ip:port>/trainer/logToken/ -H "Authorization: Token e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d"
```

Results in:

```
AnonymousUser
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'trainer',)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
)
```

View:

```
def logToken(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

Any ideas? I tried to log using Basic Authentication but with no result as well

EDIT:
When I execute:

```
curl -viL -H "Authorization: Token e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d" http://<ip:port>/trainer/logToken/
```

I get:

```
    * About to connect() to <IP> port 8000 (#0)
    *   Trying <IP>...
    * Adding handle: conn: 0x25b82c0
    * Adding handle: send: 0
    * Adding handle: recv: 0
    * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
    * - Conn 0 (0x25b82c0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
    * Connected to <IP> (<IP>) port 8000 (#0)
    > GET /trainer/logToken/ HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
    > Host: <IP>:8000
    > Accept: */*
    > Authorization: Token e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d
    >
    * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
    < HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    < Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 20:52:36 GMT
    Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 20:52:36 GMT
    < Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.2
    Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.2
    < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    < Vary: Cookie
    Vary: Cookie

    <
    AnonymousUser* Closing connection 0
```

Line below is added by default

```
  django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

EDIT2:

I added one line to my view and now it looks as below:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def logToken(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

and it works, but I have no idea why?

Comment: could you add your complete view please?

Comment: What do you get if you `curl -viL -H "Authorization: Token e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d" http://<ip:port>/trainer/logToken/` in your shell?

Comment: Have you added    `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Comment: @HåkenLid Aren't `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` added in `settings.py` by default? I do not recall adding them to any of my projects.

Comment: The request seem to be going through nice. Can you use `./manage.py shell` to double-check whether you are using correct token or not?

Comment: `Token.objects.all()
[<Token: 343d88603aad1831ff56b549f419d341799554bd>, <Token: e2a9b561fc24a65b607135857d304747a36d0e8d>]
>>>` as you can see token is fine.
Should I use some code in view to handle authentication?

Comment: Did you solve the problem by adding the `@api_view` decorator? It probably because the rest-framework authentication is not used unless you use one of the function decorators or class-based views in that package. Regular django views will only use session authentication.

Comment: Yes, apparently it helps. But it is not clear for me, because http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme says that I can set authentication scheme globally and there is no need to use `@api_view` decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `api_view` decorator, it's a regular Django view.
DRF embeds its own authentication and permission system as to avoid things such as requiring a CSRF even if you are posting data in JSON.

The counter part is that DRF extends the Django request in the `APIView` performing authentication, authorization, throttling and a few other things there. Note that the `api_view` decorator wraps an `APIView` around your function.

Therefore, with the decorator, you'll have the DRF system active while without it simply won't work.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you tell how to mix these two types of authentication, I mean regular Django session authentication and DRF Token Authentication?